# gstreamer two elements link, caps not match, can i modify the caps to make two elements match

Tags: gstreamer

Basically is that i want link element h265parse and element h265decoder,or say i want typefind can match h265decoder for h265parse.
But h265parse src Capabilities is like video/x-h265,  width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080 and have other fields.
And h265decoder sink Capabilities is like video/x-h265,  width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080,maxwidth = (int)1920,maxheight=(int)1080.
So if want typefind can match h265decoder for h265parse, h265parse src pad caps must have maxwidth and maxheight fields.
My question is that can i modify h265parse caps, or say add maxwidth and maxheight fields on h265parse src caps, but  i can't modify h265parse  element code, is there anyway that i can modify caps on pipeline control side.
And at what timing i can get  h265parse src caps, after change state like playing, gst_pad_get_current_caps returns NULL, i try gst_pad_set_event_function, it enters several times with GST_EVENT_RECONFIGURE.

I am coding with C  not gst-launch-1.0 command.
i try gst_caps_set_simple (caps, "maxwidth", G_TYPE_INT, maxwidth, "maxheight", G_TYPE_INT, maxheight, NULL); when i can get h265parse src caps by gst_pad_set_event_function,it doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you know the caps you can explicity define in a [capsfilter](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/coreelements/capsfilter.html?gi-language=c) element and put it between the other two elements. Its possible that data is not known/flowing through your pipeline, you can use [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/debugging-tools.html?gi-language=c) to generate an image of your pipeline - it will tell you which caps are flowing between elements.